# Add easier links to meta sites

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, meta, hot-questions

I am using the Worldbuilding site as an example. As of now, there is no way to easily get from the main site to meta (or back). To get there, you either have to change the URL in your browser or click one of the items in the Hot Meta Posts section and from there click the header to get to the main menu.

[image: Worldbuilding site has no link to meta]

Here is where I am proposing a change:

[image: Before- hot meta posts section]

The word meta could be linked to the meta for that site. This seems like a simple, intuitive change. Sure, it's small, but it would save everyone time without hurting the experience of new users who can easily get confused by complicated menus that lead in circles.

[image: After- the word meta has a hyperlink to the worldbuilding meta site]

The picture here didn't look right, so after a little more playing around with it, I got these. Take your pick.

[image: another pic with hyperlink]

[image: another formatting]

Comment: It's also possible to navigate to Meta via the hamburger menu (top right) and the 'Feedback' link in the footer.

Comment: This isn't universally going to solve the problem of not having a convenient link to meta because it will disappear when there are no hot meta posts (which happens quite often on some sites).

Comment: @Glorfindel Both of those are mobile-only

Comment: @Glorfindel Never mind, I found the one at the top under the sites list. Still seems inefficient though.

Comment: Good idea! Maybe the currently very empty left sidebar of the new design would be a good place to include such a link.

Comment: @samcarter Good idea, I think the bar is too simple at the moment. The bar shouldn't look like the header. Because it is out of the way, it should have more links on it than the header does.

Comment: @Laurel related to the point of there not always being a hot meta post: [Feature Improvement: Always display sub-stack meta posts in a side-bar on their main site](/q/387573)

Answer (score 12):

Meta should be more visible, but I'm not sure a direct link in the community bulletin is going to be visible enough to new users either.  (Plus, sometimes there aren't any meta posts in that bulletin, as somebody said in a comment.)  You can get to meta from the hamburger-like icon in the top right (the site navigator), but that's pretty unintuitive.  (I think most people expect settings there, not sites, because of the hamburger styling.)

Instead of using the community bulletin, let's take advantage of the (new) part of the site that is *designed* for "sub-sites": the left nav.  Currently in full use only on Stack Overflow, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

"Stack Moderators" is a Team, a type of (private) site attached to SO.  Teams are the proximate cause for left nav, as I understand it.

There's plenty of room in the left nav and meta is important, so it's worth a line there.  Because there's some extra space, it'd be even better if it said something like "Meta, for questions about this site" or "Meta Discussions", but even just "Worldbuilding Meta" like in the site selector would be informative.

Comment: If we do this we should also add a link to chat, the "third place".

Comment: Great idea! I have tried to open that menu quite a few times to find either SO meta, SE, or SE meta and been confused by their non-existence. The side bar seems almost entirely useless to me because I don't ever do badge or user searches. Adding some more links to the bar would definitely help the user experience.

Answer (score 8):

As Glorfindel commented, it's already possible to navigate to the site's meta by using the hamburger menu on the top right. This isn't mobile-only; it's available on the desktop site too:

> [image: navigate to per site meta via hamburger menu]

I think that having a link in the header would make it look ugly in my opinion, and as Laurel commented, the header would disappear if there are no hot meta posts.

I'd support having a more clear link to meta, however, as it's not clear to new users that that's how they navigate to the site's meta; I think a lot of them search Google for it and end up here, and thus ask their (site-specific and thus off-topic) question here. I remember in the old, *old* top bar (pre-November 2013, when it was themed along with the site) that there used to be a link to meta in the top bar itself; it's unlikely that it would be reinstated in the current top bar due to its design. But I disagree with this feature request as it is currently written.

Comment: Maybe Monica's option below could be used. It would put the meta somewhere easy to find but out of the way of someone not looking for it.